# Triggering a jQuery function when the page loads and when a link is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.gdthumbtext')
.contents()
.filter( function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function(){
    this.nodeValue= this.nodeValue.replace(/\+/g,'');
});

});
```

To remove plus signs before numbers inside the `.gdthumbtext` div.
Now the problem is that the number will change with ajax each time you click a link
with the class `.gdt-starrating.`

I guess I have to call (or recall) that function again when the link is clicked.

Maybe I need something like this: call the function when page loads **or** when the link with class `.gdt-starrating` is clicked.

Any suggestions of how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the code into it's own function, call that function onload then continue to call the function each time the link is clicked. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Call cleanup onload
    stripPlusSigns();

    $('a.gdt-starrating').click(function() {
        // Do stuff here...
        // ...

        // Strip plus signs again
        stripPlusSigns();
    });
});

function stripPlusSigns()
{
    $('.gdthumbtext')
        .contents()
        .filter( function(){
             return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).each(function(){
             this.nodeValue= this.nodeValue.replace(/\+/g,'');
        });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea.

You should be running it on ajax Sucess after your ajax content is loaded. I've included both click and ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // run on page load
    removeSigns();

    // you could run on ajax load
    $('.gdt-starrating').bind('click', function() {
        removeSigns();
    });

    // you should be running it on Ajax success callback
    $.ajax({ 
            // your normal ajax stuff...

        success : function() {
            removeSigns();
        } 
    });

});


function removeSigns() {
    $('.gdthumbtext')
    .contents()
    .filter( function(){
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).each(function(){
        this.nodeValue= this.nodeValue.replace(/\+/g,'');
    }
```

);
}